# Are all orthogonal groups in $GL(n;\mathbb{R})$ of a fixed signature conjugate?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

We will say that $G<GL(n;\mathbb{R})$ is an *orthogonal group* if $G$ is abstractly isomorphic to $O(p,q)$ for some $p+q=n$.
If $G\cong O(p,q)$ is an orthogonal group, is $G$ actually *conjugate in $GL(n;\mathbb{R})$* to $O(p,q)$?

I think this follows for groups $G$ abstractly isomorphic to $O(n)$ as this is the maximal compact subgroup and hence unique up to conjugacy.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to go about proving (or looking for counterexamples) to the indefinite cases.

Comment: The wording here is a bit circular. Do you mean, If two subgroups of $GL(n, \Bbb R)$ that are both isomorphic to $O(p, q)$ for some $p, q$ (such that $p + q = n$), are they necessarily conjugate?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to say it!